# Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Tags: swift, string

If I want to print every characters in a string, I can use following code:

```
let flowers = "Flowers "
for c in flowers.characters {
print(c)
}
```

But recently, when I used the following code from apple's API [Link of API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview) and got an error(which said: Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'), is api wrong or there something else I ignored?

[image: picture]

Comment: The first code snippet shown in the linked API page is outdated (once valid in old, old Swift) and not up-to-date. It's a documentation bug and you should send a [Bug Report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple.

Comment: var flowers  = "Flowers ".characters
for c in flowers {
    print(c)
}

Answer (score 2):

```
let flowers = "Flowers "
for c in flowers.characters {
    print(c)
}
```

is valid.

Answer (score 1):

yes, the API is wrong, you should add .characters